# Most efficient way to do 2d tiles (VBO vs Instancing)

Tags: opengl, efficiency

Ok so I am looking at building a game that uses 16*16 tiles, and renders anywhere from 400,000 to 1,000,000 tiles onto the screen at any given time. The tiles will be destroyable .

What is the most efficient way of rendering them in OpenGL (3.3)?

How does a VBO compare to instancing? (Would instancing be any good in this situation?)

Answer (score 1):

Either way should be fine (although note that you need buffer objects in order to do instancing).  Your primary bottleneck is going to be elsewhere: fillrate, overdraw and ROP.

Answer (score 0):

Using a VBO means that the data for drawing will sit in GPU memory, which is better (performance wise) than if it would be in main memory.
Using instancing means drawing multiple instances of the same geometry (using different parameters based on the instance ID).

Those things do not exclude each other! You can draw with instancing from a VBO - if many of your tiles will share the same geometry this would be a way to draw it.

Comment: Ok so for drawing >400,000 tile which would be best? Straight from a VBO or instancing? Geometry should always be the same (2d quad)

Comment: Those things do not exclude each other. On a side note: If you render > 400,000 objects on a (e.g.) FullHD screen, each will end up being 5 pixel big on average (so a bit more than 2*2 pixels (2*1 pixels for 1,000,000 tiles)...). You might want to consider a level of detail technique.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's about 2D tiles and 1,000,000 is an awfully big number (so each tile will be a small rectangular area a few pixels big), the most efficient way of doing this would be to draw a textured fullscreen triangle. Really, no kidding. There's no need for geometry here.

UXGA only has 1,920,000 pixels total (1.9 pixels per tile), and 1080p will have just about 2.07 pixels per tile at 1M tiles. That's perfectly adequate for drawing a textured quad (or triangle, which is more efficient, avoiding double shader invocation on the diagonal).

Have two PBOs to update the texture, and set alpha to zero (or color to black, or whatever) when you "destroy" a tile.